# How promising is Flex/Flash as a development path for the iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, flash, slider

[2015 update: I think it's [safe to say](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/aug/24/adobe-flash-dying-amazon-google-chrome?) that Flash is rapidly dying. Don't go there. Gotta say though, during its brief moment to shine, Flex was actually a really lovely datavis technique.]

I'm interested in developing for the iPad and iPhone, but I'd prefer not to learn Apple's whole development stack (and good golly, I sure don't want to go back to manual memory management). Oh, sure, I *could* learn it, but I don't have that level of commitment to the environment at this point. I've got professional experience with Flex already, so I'm intrigued by Adobe's [move](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/mobile/) to make Flash/Flex compile to the iPhone and iPad. My question is: how promising of a development path will Adobe's Slider be? Are we likely to see Slider publicly available in a reasonable timeframe (Adobe: "An early mobile branch of the Flex framework is expected to be available in 2010")? Are we likely to see reasonable performance? Are there development hurdles that haven't become clear yet? Heck, is it all just vaporware? There's pretty limited information available so far, as far as I've seen, but I'm interested in people's predictions, even if they're speculative.

Comment: Probably shouldn't ask for "speculation"-- that's a good way to get your question closed. :)

Comment: Not going to happen. Flash will not be on iPhone or iPad.

Comment: "Oh, sure, I could learn it, but I don't have that level of commitment to the environment at this point." With an attitude like that, I'm sure the attention to detail in your applications will be exquisite.

Comment: @Todd - it's already there. The feature that the questioner is asking about is not released yet, but there are already apps in the iTunes store that were made with beta versions of it.

Comment: Flash is not on iPhone or iPad. CS5 does not run on either. It can compile the Flash project to Objective C for iPhone. The end result is a native iPhone app.

Comment: Todd: compiling Flash content into iPhone apps is what this question is about. It's true that Flash is not there as a browser plugin, but irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe's cross-compilation tech is not vaporware (for Flash, anyways-- haven't seen as much re: Flex). And they would be unlikely to invest so much in it if they thought it would get torpedoed on day one. That said, you must draw your own conclusions about your long-term reliance on it, and your interest in building on a non-native toolchain, both in terms of what you can get out of the environment, and the support channels you'll need to use (e.g. not Apple) when stuff doesn't work.

Some people seem to be successfully using [Mono touch](http://monotouch.net/), which shares (some) similarities.

Comment: Doesn't MonoTouch have the same non-native toolchain issues that bother you in Flash/Flex?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you'll see some info on Slider soon that will give you a better sense of the timeframe. Flex 4 will be released soon and once that happens you should start to hear more concrete info about Slider.

One thing to keep in mind is that Slider will be based on the Flex 4 architecture. To give you an idea of how that performs you can check out James Ward's blog post - http://www.jamesward.com/2010/02/21/flex-performance-on-mobile-devices/ - he's got a couple of videos that show a Flex 4 list running on a Nexus One.

This isn't iPad/iPhone, and Flex is NOT something Adobe recommends for mobile, but this basic example works pretty well. And it should give you an idea of how Slider might look/behave.

=Ryan
ryan@adobe.com

Comment: Thanks, Ryan, this is really hepful.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, Apple's new developer agreement [calls into question](http://daringfireball.net/2010/04/iphone_agreement_bans_flash_compiler) whether apps built with Flash/Flex will be allowed:

> 3.3.1 — Applications may only use Documented APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any private APIs. Applications must be originally written in Objective-C, C, C++, or JavaScript as executed by the iPhone OS WebKit engine, and only code written in C, C++, and Objective-C may compile and directly link against the Documented APIs (e.g., Applications that link to Documented APIs through an intermediary translation or compatibility layer or tool are prohibited).

Comment: Yes, it is now officially banned.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with this:

1. Steve Jobs says he isn't going to support Flash on iPhone or iPad.
2. Adobe's next rev is going to allow you to develop in Flex and port to iPhone app format.

Do the math.

Comment: Actually, the iPhone preview won't really support Flex. Flex apps *might* work, but they're not going to be part of the supported workflow and they probably won't perform well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start iPhone, iPa or Mac OSX development, I'd suggest learning Objective-C. It'll probably take less time than waiting for (official) Flash support on those devices ... 
Take it the other way around, would you use Objective-C to develop a Flash or a Flex app?

Answer (score 0):

Flex can now compile iOS applications (and so run on the ipad and iphone)

http://gregsramblings.com/2011/06/20/finally-its-here-flex-on-ios-android-and-blackberry-playbook/

http://gregsramblings.com/2011/04/26/convincing-developers-that-adobe-flex-rocks-on-android-ios-and-playbook/